# mybatis use input param as argument in constructor

Tags: mybatis

In mybatis, can i use an input @Param object in the resultMap constructor?

```
int test(@Param("param1") someObj obj, @Param("str") String str);

 <resultMap id="testResultMap" type="com.test.someOtherObject">
   <constructor>
      <idArg column="id" javaType="String"/>
      <arg column="<use the input param obj of type someObj>"   javaType="com.test.someObj"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: Parameters and result maps are 2 distinct things. You cannot feed the result map directly from parameter.

If you want the input parameter to be in the result Map, then it must be in the result set, so you must either select the corresponding column if you filter on that column: `SELECT col FROM t WHERE col = #{param}`or add it as pseudo column: `SELECT '${param}' AS "colName" FROM t` and map it as usual with parameterized constructor if you like.

If the constructor argument is a complex type then use `<arg resultMap="anotherResultMap" />` instead of `<arg column="col" />`.